# C# parse Elasticsearch date throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

i have extracted a csv file from Elastic(Kibana) and i have a date in format like this:

> Dec 6, 2022 @ 23:59:59.000

I'm trying to parse this string:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("Dec 6, 2022 @ 23:59:59.000");
```

but i obtain exception:

> String 'Dec 6, 2022 @ 23:59:59.000' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can i parse this type of string in a DateTime?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @phuzi using DateTime.ParseExact and with the right format, I managed to parse the date, here is the code:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("Dec 6, 2022 @ 23:59:59.000", "MMM d, yyyy @ HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thank you